# Evaluation of $\iint_{D}\left(x\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Suppose that $f(x,y)$ is defined on $D=\{(x,y)\mid x^2+y^2\le1\}$ and has continuous second-order partial derivatives in $D$. If

$$\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y^2}=\mathrm{e}^{-(x^2+y^2)}$$

then find $\iint_{D}\left(x\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y$.

I have tried the polar coordinate form, obtained

$$
\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}  =\cos^2\theta\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial r^2}-\frac{2\sin\theta\cos\theta}{r}\cdot\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial r\partial \theta}+\frac{\sin^2\theta}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial\theta^2}+\frac{\sin^2\theta}{r}\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}+\frac{2\sin\theta\cos\theta}{r^2}\frac{\partial f}{\partial\theta}\\
\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y^2}  =\sin^2\theta\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial r^2}+\frac{2\sin\theta\cos\theta}{r}\cdot\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial r\partial \theta}+\frac{\cos^2\theta}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial\theta^2}+\frac{\cos^2\theta}{r}\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}-\frac{2\sin\theta\cos\theta}{r^2}\frac{\partial f}{\partial\theta}\\
\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y^2} =\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial r^2}+\frac1r\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}+\frac1{r^2}\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial\theta^2}=\mathrm{e}^{-r^2}
$$

and

\begin{equation*}
x\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=r\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}
\end{equation*}

so, the double integral becomes

$$\iint_D r\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}r\mathrm{d}r\mathrm{d}\theta$$

how to solve this?

Comment: Are you familiar with Green's Theorem? Look at this curve $\gamma = \{e^{\theta i}: 0 \leq \theta \leq 2 \pi \}$

Comment: yes, i have tried that, that i cant continue to solve too

Comment: In this boundary, you can solve $$f_\gamma(x,y) = \frac{x^2}{2 e}+C_1(y+i x)+C_2(y-i x),$$ since $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y^2}=\mathrm{e}^{-1}$

Comment: how to find P(x, y) and Q(x, y) such that $\int_{\gamma}P(x, y)\mathrm{d}x+Q(x, y)\mathrm{d}y=\iint_{D}x\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y$? how can you obtain $f_{\gamma}(x, y)=\frac{x^2}{2e}+\cdots$? I see $x^2$ in your $f_{\gamma}$, so what if $y^2$ appears/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@H.R. posted a solid solution that used vector analysis.  I thought it would be useful to some readers to see a solution that relies on scalar analysis only.  To that end we proceed.

Let $D$ be the unit disk, centered at the origin, and let $I$ be the integral of interest defined as

$$\begin{align}
I&=\int_{D}\left(x\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)\,dS\\\\
&=\int_{-1}^1 \left(\int_{-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-y^2}}x\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \,dx\right)\,dy+\int_{-1}^1 \left(\int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}y\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \,dy\right)\,dx \tag 1
\end{align}$$

We integrate by parts the inner integral of the first integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$.  We let $u= \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}$ and $v=\frac12\left(x^2+y^2\right)$ to reveal

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-y^2}}x\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \,dx&=\left .\left(\frac12\left(x^2+y^2\right)\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)\right|_{x=-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-y^2}}-\int_{-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-y^2}} \left(\frac12\left(x^2+y^2\right)\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}\right)dx\\\\
&=\frac12\left .\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)\right|_{x=-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-y^2}}-\int_{-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-y^2}} \left(\frac12\left(x^2+y^2\right)\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}\right)dx \tag 2
\end{align}$$

An analogous development of the second integral on the right-hand side of $(2)$ reveals

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}y\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \,dy&=\frac12\left .\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)\right|_{y=-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}-\int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \left(\frac12\left(x^2+y^2\right)\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}\right)dy \tag 3
\end{align}$$

Combining the results of $(2)$ and $(3)$ yields

$$\begin{align}
I&=\frac12\oint_{x^2+y^2=1}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dy-\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dx\right)-\frac12\int_D \left(x^2+y^2\right)\left(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}\right)\,dS\\\\
&=\frac12 \int_D \left(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}\right)\,dS-\frac12\int_D \left(x^2+y^2\right)\left(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}\right)\,dS\\\\
&=\frac12\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1 \left(1-\rho^2\right)e^{-\rho^2}\,\rho\,d\rho\,d\phi\\\\
&=\frac12 \pi e^{-1}
\end{align}$$

Comment: @H.R. Thank you! Much appreciative.  The elegance of vector analysis becomes apparent. - Mark

Comment: Hi! Perhaps asking you a question from 8 years ago is very abrupt. How to get $\frac{1}{2}\oint_{x^2+y^2=1}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dy-\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dx\right)$ as you write in the fourth line from the end? Thank you~

Comment: @Ychen Write out the line integral and see if you can reconcile that they are identical.

Comment: Thanks! I get it, use variable substitution to turn the curve integral into a definite integral.

Answer (score 6):

First, note this identity

$$\psi \nabla ^2 \phi=\nabla \cdot (\psi \nabla \phi)-\nabla \psi \cdot \nabla \phi \tag{1}$$

Now, choose $\phi=f$ and $\psi=\frac{1}{2}{\bf{x}}\cdot{\bf{x}}=\frac{1}{2}|{\bf{x}}|^2$ where $\bf{x}$ is the position vector. Then equation $(1)$ becomes

$$\frac{1}{2}|{\bf{x}}|^2 \nabla ^2 f=\nabla \cdot (\frac{1}{2}|{\bf{x}}|^2 \nabla f)-{\bf{x}} \cdot \nabla f \ \\
{\bf{x}} \cdot \nabla f=\nabla \cdot (\frac{1}{2}|{\bf{x}}|^2 \nabla f)- \frac{1}{2}|{\bf{x}}|^2 \nabla ^2 f \\
\tag{2}$$

Next, we integrate over the domain $D$, use the divergence theorem, and $\nabla^2f=e^{-|{\bf{x}}|^2}$ to get

$$\int_{D}{\bf{x}} \cdot \nabla f d_{A}=\int_{\partial D} \frac{1}{2}|{\bf{x}}|^2 \nabla f \cdot {\bf{n}} d_{L} - \int_{D} \frac{1}{2}|{\bf{x}}|^2 \text{e}^{-|{\bf{x}}|^2}d_{A}\tag{3}$$

and noting that $|{\bf{x}}|=1$ on $\partial D$ will lead to

$$2\int_{D}{\bf{x}} \cdot \nabla fd_{A}=\int_{\partial D}  \nabla f \cdot {\bf{n}} d_{L} - \int_{D} |{\bf{x}}|^2 \text{e}^{-|{\bf{x}}|^2}d_{A}\tag{4}$$

Again, use the Divergence theorem for the first integral on the RHS of $(4)$

$$\begin{align}
2\int_{D}{\bf{x}} \cdot \nabla fd_{A} &= \int_{D}  \nabla \cdot \nabla f d_{A} - \int_{D} |{\bf{x}}|^2 \text{e}^{-|{\bf{x}}|^2}d_{A} \\
2\int_{D}{\bf{x}} \cdot \nabla fd_{A} &= \int_{D}  \nabla^2 f d_{A} - \int_{D} |{\bf{x}}|^2 \text{e}^{-|{\bf{x}}|^2}d_{A} \\
2\int_{D}{\bf{x}} \cdot \nabla fd_{A} &= \int_{D}  \text{e}^{-|{\bf{x}}|^2} d_{A} - \int_{D} |{\bf{x}}|^2 \text{e}^{-|{\bf{x}}|^2}d_{A}\\
\tag{5}
\end{align}$$

and the final result will be

$$\boxed{I=\int_{D}{\bf{x}} \cdot \nabla f= \frac{1}{2}\int_{D} \left(1-|{\bf{x}}|^2\right) \text{e}^{-|{\bf{x}}|^2}d_{A}}\tag{6}$$

You can evaluate the integral in RHS of $(6)$ using polar coordinates

$$\begin{align}
I &= \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1} \left(1-r^2\right) e^{-r^2}rdrd\theta \\
&= \pi \int_{0}^{1} r \left(1-r^2\right) e^{-r^2} dr \\
&=\color{blue}{\boxed{\frac{\pi}{2\text{e}}}}\tag{7}
\end{align}$$

Comment: yes, I am wait for if there is another idea, your method is excellent and correct. can you tell me how you get this idea? if my method can't solve this, why. btw this result is familar to me, it seems like $\int_0^1x^x(1-x)^{1-x}\sin\pi x\mathrm{d}x$, maybe equals $\frac{\pi}{24\pi}$.

Comment: As it comes to Laplacian, I always think of Green's identity. The equation $(1)$, which is used here is the basic idea for proving the Green's identities. So it rang a bell to investigate that whether it may become useful in this problem and it did! :)

Comment: About your solution, whatever strategy that one may use should  employ the fact that $\nabla^2f=e^{-|{\bf{x}}|^2}$.